# Bash command chaining

Tags: command-line, bash

I'd like to run chained commands but some are sequential and others are in background.

Running this command:

```
echo 1 && echo 2 & echo 3 && echo 4
```

I'd like to get:

```
1
2 (background)
3
4
```

But I get:

```
3
4
1
2
```

A more realistic example:

```
compile &&
run server &  (background, used by tests below)
run test 1 &&
run test 2 &&
kill server
```

How can I do it using bash?

Thanks!

Comment: Though not offtopic, I think that this question would be much more at home at http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I agree. Sorry about that. If an admin / moderator would like to transfer it, go for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that what you are asking for is:

```
echo 1 && { echo 2 & } && echo 3 && echo 4
```

In the above `echo 1` runs in foreground but `echo 2` runs background.

Note that the `&&` after `echo 2` may not be doing what you think.  Consider:

```
$ echo 1 && { false & } && echo 3 && echo 4
1
[2] 28445
3
4
```

The above shows that `echo 3` runs even though the second command `false` returns failure.  This is because the return code for the background process is not available when the decision to start `echo 3` is made.

Let's consider your more realistic example:

```
compile && { run server & } && run test 1 && run test 2 && kill server
```

`run test 1` will start regardless of whether `run server` succeeded or failed.  Worse than that, `run test 1` may start before `run server` has finished setting up the server.  A quick fix is to delay `run test 1` by enough time that you are confident that `run server` has finished doing its setup:

```
compile && { run server & } && sleep 1 && run test 1 && run test 2 && kill server
```

Alternatively, you would need to know something about `run server` so that you can test its successful setup.

#### Background

- The braces, `{...}`, create a list.  Thus the construct `{ echo 2 & }` allows us to run `echo 2` with the effect of the operator `&` confined to just the commands in the list.
- `&&` is bash's logical and.  The command following the `&&` is run only if the prior command succeeds, that is, returns with code 0.

Answer (score 0):

You can use nohup to run a command in background :
echo 1 && nohup echo 2 && echo 3

```
1
nohup: ignoring input and appending output to ‘nohup.out’
3
```